# How to compile TCL from source code to enable memory command in tclsh

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, tcl

I am trying to find a memory leak problem of a daemon writing with TCL, and the daemon is running on OSX continue to monitor the systems of a SAN system.

After googling the Net, I found that TCL experts said that I have to compile with TCL_MEM_DEBUG specifically defined in
the makefile (with -DTCL_MEM_DEBUG in the CFLAGS). Then Tcl will have the ‘memory’ command to log the status for memory usage.

According to the TCL’s man page, To enable memory debugging, Tcl should be recompiled from scratch  with
       TCL_MEM_DEBUG defined (e.g. by passing the --enable-symbols=mem flag to
       the configure script when building).  This will also compile in a  non-
       stub version of Tcl_InitMemory to add the memory command to Tcl.

So, I downloaded the source code tcl8.6.1-src.tar.gz from SourceForge. Extracted to a directory and change to macosx subdirectory. But after compiling with following commands

```
sudo ./configure --enable-symbols=mem
sudo make
sudo make install NATIVE_TCLSH="/usr/local/bin/tclsh8.6"
```

Although new tclsh (v8.6) was created, but the ‘memory’ command still can not work. After digging into the process, I found that some error messages were created in config.log

```
configure: failed program was: 
| /* confdefs.h.  */ 
|  
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "tcl"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "tcl" 
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "8.6" 
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "tcl 8.6" 
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "" 
| /* end confdefs.h.  */ 
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
```

I also can not find the 'confdefs.h' file by find command. What's wrong with me?

This is my MBP’s environment

MacBookPro8,2 Memory:4 GB, 15-inch, Early 2011, OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)

```
declare -x DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
declare -x PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin"
```

How to fix the problem?
Or Is there any place to download a tcl package with TCL_MEM_DEBUG enable?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to make sure you have a working compiler installation. If you haven't already, get Xcode from the Apple Store as that includes a sane command-line compiler. (The test that is failing during configuration is a check that the compiler is behaving sanely; yours is not!)

Done that? Good.

Next, only installation to some locations on disk requires `sudo` (but the default location, `/usr/local`, is one of those places). You *should not* configure or compile with it. The sequence of commands that I would use to build and install a debug-enabled Tcl on OSX would be:

```
cd $the_unpacked_tcl_dir
cd unix
./configure --enable-symbols=mem
make
sudo make install
```

Tweakables/notes:

1. You can install Tcl in locations provided you configure it for those locations with `--prefix=/the/base/install/dir` (which would put `tclsh` in `/the/base/install/dir/bin` and the Tcl shared library in `/the/base/install/dir/lib`). If the place you choose is writable by you by default, you do not need `sudo`.
2. You can (and maybe should) run the test suite between the `make` and the `make install`. Do this using `make test`. Do *not* run `make test` as the administrative user; this makes some tests fail (e.g., those that check that unwritable files are detected and reported as unwritable).
3. You can use `all` instead of `mem` to enable further debugging options, especially in relation to the bytecode compiler.
4. Using `--enable-symbols` at all may well reduce performance substantially, disabling the more advanced C compiler options, causing different memory tracking to be used, and adding additional overhead to the bytecode engine to enable instruction-level tracing. If you want speed, *do not use it at all*.
5. If you have tried to do `make` before, you should run `make clean` after `./configure` and before `make`. (You can combine these steps by doing `make clean all`; the default `make` target is `all`.)

Be aware that I use debug-enabled builds of Tcl on OSX (Mountain Lion right now) a lot; this *is* a tested configuration. Whatever is going on is *not* a bug with Tcl.

Comment: Donal, thank you! 
In fact, I upgraded Xcode to v5.0.2 from previous version, and installed Command Line Tools by xcode-select --instal. The output of 'xcode-select -p' now is '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. I will try to remove Xcode and reinstall it later, and follow your steps to solve the problem. Donal, Thanks again.

Comment: How to make sure the command line tools has been installed properly? I've downloaded a version for 10.9 and install it. But still can not do the ./configure --enable-symbols=mem correctly, the error in the log was still. And if use xcode-select --install, will get a error dialog 'Can't install the software because it is not current available from the Software Update server'. So, what can I do?

Comment: @charles.hsu Well, it all Just Works for me, but then I'm on 10.8 (out of laziness and having rather too many ssh sessions open). This sounds like something more for Apple Support (or at least http://apple.stackexchange.com/)