# Setting mem configure option in TCL build script

Tags: tcl

I need to build Activestate TCL for Ubuntu 18.04 with memory option enabled, "--enable-symbols=mem flag to the configure script" but there is no configure script in my download, only these, which don't have a "configure" line in them.

```
license-at8.6-thread.
update_check
komodo_download
payload
README-8.6-thread.txt
pdemos
install_welcome.txt
install.tcl
install.sh
install_lib.tcl
install_images
MANIFEST_at8.6.txt
install_data.tcl
```

Can someone describe how to add the switch described above for Ubuntu?
.

Comment: A configure script comes with the source code for software, but Activestate Tcl is for already compiled binaries.

Comment: Is there any reason that you are insisting on ActiveState Tcl? Why not build Tcl from source on Ubuntu for that purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964007/how-to-compile-tcl-from-source-code-to-enable-memory-command-in-tclsh? Or, obtain the Ubuntu battery Tcl via `apt`, and rebuild via `apt source`?

Comment: I tried that, now the SourceForge download is missing a tclConfig.sh file in the download directory,  I used "find" there is no such file in the download.

Checking for Tcl configuration... configure: error: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions. Use --with-tcl to specify a directory containing tclConfig.sh

Comment: `--with-tcl` ... so you are compiling a Tcl extension (which?), not Tcl itself. And you want to mem-debug that extension (along with a mem-debug enabled core)? You should update your Q with the exact steps to reproduce.

Comment: Thx mrcalvin for checking on this.  I reposted my comment with a note of clarification.  

There is a file tclconfig/install.sh in my download, but even if I rename that file tclConfig.sh, the configure command barfs, says it can't find the file: > ./configure --prefix=/opt/tcl --with-tcl tclconfig > checking for Tcl configuration... configure: error: yes directory doesn't contain tclConfig.sh > if test -f "tclconfig/tclConfig.sh" ; then echo "yes"; fi > yes

........The "--tcl_config"  was just an experiment to see if the tclConfig.sh file was in the lower directory.  It was not.

Comment: Also, thanks to MoDJ and Donal for advice, very much appreciated.

Comment: I posted a ticket on SourceForge too, asking to advise on where this README-referenced file is located.

Comment: More info I found:  The Ubuntu site seems to have TCL downloads "with threads," and downloads like "tcl-dbg," but not both.  I need both threads and debug enabled, so I think Ubuntu doesn't have what I need.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the `mem` option, you'll need to compile Tcl from source. To do that you'll need to get a C build chain (especially a C compiler such as `gcc` or `clang`, and `make` to act as a build orchestrator) and the Tcl (and Tk) source code for the version you want to build. The *official* location for releases of Tcl sources is on SourceForge:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/

Pick the version you need and the download package you prefer (ZIP or compressed Tar archive).

Once you've downloaded and unpacked the Tcl code, change into the appropriate directory within the distribution (e.g., `unix` for Linux builds) and run the `configure` script inside; it's *that script* that you pass the `--enable-symbols=mem` option to.

---

ActiveTcl is essentially built the same way (except without symbols at all; it's a production distribution after all). It's main distinguishing feature is that it is set up with access to lots of extra packages to go with it. The same goes for most Linux distributions' own `tcl` packages. They're all *production distributions* and aren't configured for memory debugging precisely because that adds a lot of overhead to the code (both time and space).